# Can I use Bonjour to connect two iOS devices one in 3G network and one with WiFi

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, bonjour

I am developing an iPhone app in which I need to connect my iPhone with any of the available iPhones around it using 3G and WiFi network. One of the iPhone should be in 3G network and the other should have only WiFi connection. I **cant use Bluetooth** as the range of connection should be >10 m.

I am wondering if it is possible to use **Bonjour** protocol to achieve the connection between two iPhones when one is on 3G connection and other is on WiFi, and there is no other network present around.

If not how can I connect two ios devices with one on 3G and one on WiFi, without using Bluetooth.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Used to be possible between Macs using the Back To My Mac service described here but never made it to iPhone and sadly its even gone from the Mac now: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_My_Mac

Answer (score 3):

Here's Apple's example how to transfer data between two devices via Wi-Fi that uses Bonjour protocol: [WiTap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html).

hope this helps......

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have tried WiTap app, it works with wifi. My app needs to communicate between devices in two different LAN/WAN. Devices may not have access to wifi when it is used. Any hint is helpful.

Comment: i think u need write socket programming for that.......try for socket programming concept i will update u soon.....